# How to use `dir="auto"` with Angular Material's textarea?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

## Working example with normal `textarea`

If you have this code code:

```html
<textarea dir="auto"></textarea>
```

And you start writing, e.g., Arabic, you'll find that the text is automatically right-aligned, as it should be.

## Non-working example with Angular Material's `textarea`

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Post</mat-label>
  <textarea dir="auto" matInput></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you start writing, e.g., Arabic, unfortunately, the text remains left-aligned :(

## The question

So, the question: How to use `dir="auto"` with Angular Material's `textarea`? Or how to get the text right-aligned in Angular Material's `textarea` when the user starts writing Arabic automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I couldn't even get `dir="rtl"` to work with Angular Material's `textarea`. But thanks to the [the example in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10186), seems like it's possible by setting `dir="rtl"` on the parent form.

So, perhaps a temporary workaround is possible by having the `form`'s `dir` attribute take its value from a member variable, and take this variable's value from the user or calculate it based on the first character in the `textarea` or something.

But yeah, not a perfect solution and I hope someone has a better one. But it partially answers my question so I'm going to leave it here in case it's a solution for someone else as well.